How can I get the stack trace of unexpected errors with Chai?
I am using Chai with Mocha. I write tests something like this:
expect(() => f(a, b)).to.throw('Sriharikota we have a problem.')

I want to show the stack trace of the original error when it does not match the specified message. For example, if the error message is 'Houston we have a problem.', then I would like to get a full stack trace. This is a big help in diagnosing bugs where the test fails in a place other than it should.
I tried setting chai.config.includeStack = true, but this just gives me a stack trace like the following, which shows only the stack inside Chai itself and in my test module, not inside the code being tested:
      at Proxy.assertThrows (node_modules/chai/lib/chai/core/assertions.js:2730:16)
      at Proxy.methodWrapper (node_modules/chai/lib/chai/utils/addMethod.js:57:25)
      at Context.<anonymous> (/path/to/my/code/test/mytest.ts:31:53)
      at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:478:21)


That's expected, as chai is constructing the error. For your purpose you can use a coverage reporter and run a single test

Many thanks, I'll look into that.

What is a "coverage reporter"? I'm familiar with coverage programs like nyc and c8, but I'm not sure how using them would help. I checked Mocha's documentation, and it only seems to mention coverage in this sense. Sorry if I'm being dense!

Exactly libs like npm and c8 with them you can see all the lines of the code/branches which have been executed.

Imagine having a global variable being incremented in multiple places in your code. And then having a test that the variable has to be less than 0, what trace would you expect to see? Trace to all of the paces where the value have been incremented?

Ah, so this is a workaround rather than getting me an actual stack trace?
